# Why can't I target .Net 6 in my VS2022 Windows App?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio

I have to maintain an old legacy Windows .Net Forms C# app.
I can open and build the app as-is in VS2022, targetting .Net 4.8, but I like to target .Net 6 now. However .Net 6 is not an option in the project preferences.

[image]

If I click where it says "Install other frameworks..." then it takes me to the same place that I downloaded and installed .Net 6 from.

I've confirmed that .Net 6 SDK is installed, (by runing *dotnet --version* from the command line) and I do not have a global.json file anywhere that I can find.

Also, if I create a new .Net Forms App, it will let me target .Net 6

So, how do I update the older project to be able to target .net 6?

Comment: You can't just retarget an old .NET Framework app to .NET6, you need to create a new app and migrate code over.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. You can't migrate from .NET Framework to .NET Core simply by changing a version number. Check [Upgrade a Windows Forms App to .NET 6 with the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework).